# VBScript: Passing parameters to function

Tags: function, vbscript, parameter-passing

I have 2 functions. I need to pass a parameter from one to another and evaluate it in 2nd function. For the below code I need "QA" in env but its printing it as "env"

```
strenv = "QA"
cus_number = getNumber(strenv)

If (IsNull(cus_number)) Then
    WScript.Echo "Number is null" 
Else
 WScript.Echo "cus_number : " & cus_number
End If



 Function getNumber(strenv)
    wscript.echo "env: " & strenv
    if strenv = "QA" Then
     number = "423"
    elseif strenv ="DEV" Then
      number= "678"
    endif
     getNumber=number
    End Function
```

Comment: The  code  you've posted doesn't even compile (it generates a "compilation error" for invalid syntax), much less run or do anything wrong. Please [edit] your question to provide a real, running sample of the code that isn't working correctly for you.

Comment: @Ken White: I have updated the code

Comment: -1 Had you actually tried running the code you just posted, you'd have noticed that it still throws compilation errors. The error message even tells you where and why.

Comment: I have updated  the code now.How can I read the parameter strenv inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 2 issues in your code:

1. `strenv = QA`

   You probably meant to assign the string `"QA"` to the variable `strenv`. However, without double qoutes `QA` is regarded a variable. Since you didn't initialize it, its value is `Empty`, which is then assigned to `strenv`.
2. The syntax of the conditional in the function is incorrect. Please check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h27x7e9%28v=vs.84%29).

Comment: Actually I am getting QA from user input. But here for convenience I assigned it. strenv has "QA" value outside the function getNumber. But how can I get it inside the function?

Comment: @sravs448 The conditional in your function *still* has **syntax errors**. I even referred you to the relevant documentation. Please remove the `On Error Resume Next` the you seem to have somewhere in your real code and do your homework.

Comment: I can take care of conditions. I have updated it now. Please let me know the way to access the parameter which is passed.

Comment: The logic in your code is correct. It's your syntax that isn't. You still have a syntax error (in line 18 of your sample code). `endif` (without a space) is not a valid keyword in VBScript.